# ember refresh/reload model after change data in mirage

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I need to refresh/reload my model-hook again after I did changes like add or edit my modal by an action. I have seen a lot of topics like this but either there are deprecated or not working in my case.

This is my component.js-file called "listing.js":

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
    actions: {
        togglePower: function(a){
            console.log(a);
            var data = new Array();
            data.push(a);
            $.ajax({
                cache:false,
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/api/device",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json"
                })

                this.get('users.single.households.single.rooms.single.devices.single').send('refresh');
        }
      }
});
```

Mirage receives my data and is able to work with it. But for now I need to reload my page to see my changes. So I tried to add the last line in the listing.js which is

```
this.get('users.single.households.single.rooms.single.devices.single').send('refresh');
```

But this doesn´t work for me. The console comes up with:

> TypeError: this.get(...) is undefined

This is my route:

```
        model(){
...},
        actions: {
            refresh: function() {
                this.refresh();
              }
            }

>     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to call refresh, you have to use closure actions. After the ajax in your component file you need to do

```
this.get('on-refresh')();
```

'on-refresh' is a function passed to the component. In this case it is the refresh action.

```
{{listing on-refresh=(route-action "refresh")}}
```

`route-action` comes from this add-on https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper which allows you to call route actions directly from the template without passing through the controller.

So what we did here is pass a the refresh function to the component, and then the component calls it when needed.

Comment: Thank you. This helps but not completely work. I put  this.get('on-refresh')(); under my ajax in listing.js and {{listing on-refresh=(route-action "refresh")}} in the top of my listing.hbs. It extremely slows down my site and i can´t load it. But a Button like this <button {{action (route-action 'refresh')}}>Update sFoo</button> works fine. Can i just call this action after my togglePower action? Maybe directly after my ajax?

Comment: This might also slow down your site, try checking why it's taking a while to load. 
Also I forgot to mention that you need to call `this.get('on-refresh')` after the ajax finishes. `$.ajax().then(() => {  this.get('on-refresh')()  })`

Comment: I moved it to the then part of the ajax and got an error: _this.get(...) is not a function

Comment: Are you using the arrow function notation?

Comment: yes. I have solved the problem with using the bubbling like this:
    <div {{action (route-action 'refresh')}} class="col-12 col-md-12">
         <div class="listcontent" ><img {{action 'togglePower' device.id}} class="icons" src="path" alt=""></div>
    </div>

Maybe dirty but it works for now :D